# Mocking a system communicating with JMS messages on IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have two applications SystemA and SystemB communicating via request and response messages and using correlation IDs.

I would like to be able to test SystemA in isolation without having to rely on the availability of our IBM MQ broker and SystemB. Ideally I would like to do it in our continuous integration environment (Jenkins). I am looking for common approaches to this problem, before I code a solution myself in-house.

How can I create a mockup of the IBM MQ broker and SystemB for the purpose of testing SystemA in isolation?

Answer (score 1):

Why mock the queue?  Have you considered mocking the consumer from the queue instead?  This would be simpler and would leave the queues in place for when the full featured service became available.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for both basic and advanced mocking and simulation for developers and testers and would like to do [black box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) have a look at [Traffic Parrot](http://trafficparrot.com/) and this [mocking and simulating JMS IBM WebSphere MQ tutorial](http://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/mocking-or-simulating-jms-ibm-websphere-mq.html). It will work in Jenkins as well.

If you do not need to do black box testing, and can mock stuff in unit tests, just use [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) or a similar java mocking library.